# Setting a Sheet Name to a User Defined Variable, then Referencing it in same Code

Tags: vba, excel

Still learning Excel and VBA, so apologies if the code is hideous, or this answer is simple.

I have a set of sheets that are tied to a checkbox; if the box is checked they come out of hidden and the row they are tied to in "SUMMARY" is unhidden, and vice versa. I am trying to make a set of sheets that get renamed to the contents of a specific cell in "Control" sheet, and then operate as though the name in the "Control" sheet has always been their name. I have tried setting variables, establishing ranges, and have failed each time. What do I need to do to have an existing sheet be renamed according to the cell in "Control" I9, and then operate from that point on as though the new name has been the name all along?

Would it be better to have the checkbox simply make a new sheet, format it as I need, and then name it to the user defined variable?

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    If CheckBox40.Value = True Then
         DIM Name AS String
            Name = Sheets("Control").Cells(9 "I")

        ActiveWorkbook.Unprotect 
        Sheets("ALL 1").Unprotect 
        Sheets("SUMMARY").Unprotect 

        Sheets("ALL 1").Visible = -1
        Worksheets("SUMMARY").Rows("25").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Worksheets("SUMMARY").Cells(25, 2).Value = "ALL 1"
        Worksheets("SUMMARY").Cells(25, 3).Value = "INTEGRATED AUTOMATION"
        Worksheets("SUMMARY").Cells(25, 4).Value = "='Control'!F26"
        Worksheets("SUMMARY").Cells(25, 5).Value = "='Control'!G26"
        Worksheets("SUMMARY").Cells(25, 6).Value = "='ALL 1'!$H$69"
        Worksheets("SUMMARY").Cells(25, 7).Value = "='ALL 1'!$J$69"
        Worksheets("SUMMARY").Cells(25, 8).Value = "='ALL 1'!$N$69"
        Worksheets("SUMMARY").Cells(25, 9).Value = "='ALL 1'!$P$69"
        Worksheets("SUMMARY").Cells(25, 10).Value = "=SUM(F25:I25)/D25"
        Worksheets("SUMMARY").Cells(25, 11).Value = "=M25/F3"
        Worksheets("SUMMARY").Cells(25, 12).Value = "='ALL 1'!$U$69"
        Worksheets("SUMMARY").Cells(25, 13).Value = "=M25/$K$57"

        ActiveWorkbook.Protect True, True
        Sheets("ALL 1").Protect True, True
        Sheets("SUMMARY").Protect True, True
        Sheets("ALL 1").Name = Name
End If

If CheckBox40.Value = False Then

        ActiveWorkbook.Unprotect 
        Sheets("ALL 1").Unprotect 
        Sheets("SUMMARY").Unprotect 

        Sheets("ALL 1").Visible = 2
        Worksheets("SUMMARY").Rows("25").EntireRow.ClearContents
        Worksheets("SUMMARY").Rows("25").EntireRow.Hidden = True

        ActiveWorkbook.Protect True, True
        Sheets("ALL 1").Protect True, True
        Sheets("SUMMARY").Protect True, True
        Sheets("ALL 1").Name = Name

End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you trying to set a sheet name according to a value in a specified cell?

Comment: Yes, which I can do. The problem is that the SUMMARY sheet needs to reference the newly named worksheet's cells, which is where I am running into issues.

Comment: You can always refer your worksheets by its codename. Codename is fixed and do not change. Using Sheet1(summary) as an example, Sheet1 is the codename and summary is the sheet tab name. Sheets("summary").Select is the same as Sheet1.Select  http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/excel-vba-sheet-names.htm

Comment: Right, but the issue is where I have to set Values in the "SUMMARY" cells equal to cells in the new worksheet with a variable name. I guess I need to know if I can use a variable worksheet name in a formula to pull the values I need over.

Answer (score 2):

Use a worksheet variable to hold the renamed sheet and then use that to build your formulas:

```
DIM myName AS String  'don't use "name" as the name of a variable, it's a property
Dim ws as worksheet  
MyName = Sheets("Control").Cells(9 "I")
set ws = worksheets("All 1")  'point to "All 1"
ws.name = MyName  'rename All 1 to something else
Worksheets("SUMMARY").Cells(25, 12).Value = "='" & ws.name & "'!$U$69"  
'keeps pointing to whatever All 1 is now called
```

Comment: Thanks! I was beating my head against the wall trying to solve this.